# SW recommendations to manage a pool of hostnames

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, hostname, system-administration

I'm looking for SW options to manage a pool of hostnames, nothing fancy, but hopefully something that can run on a container so I can deploy it on Kubernetes.

I have like 50~ or so hostnames that need to be assigned dynamically to automation tools/devs on demand. For example:

- Dev A opens a ticket requesting a hostname
- Dev B opens a ticket requesting another hostname

Then the SW assigns different hostnames from an available pool to both Devs(if there are hostnames unused/available), the devs can now freely use them to say deploy their apps on Kubernetes and configure an ingress using the hostnames that the SW assigned to them.

I guess I can code my own app and deploy it but I wanted to reuse someone else's code or at least give it a try.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a great place to ask these kinds of open-ended questions since there is no one correct answer. That said, this is very weird thing to need so I'm pretty sure you're going to need to write it yourself. Check out external-dns for the DNS management at least.